# Form a flat indexed array from a multidimensional result set

Tags: php, array, sql, json

I want make my looped data into one flat array without associative keys. I have solved it with my code, but I think it is so crowded and not simple.

This my code:

```
$data = array();
while($dt = $this->db->fetchAssoc($res_weight)){
    $data[] = array_values($dt);
}
$datas = json_encode($data);
$datas = str_replace("[","",$datas);
$datas = str_replace("]","",$datas);
$datas = '['.$datas.']';
$datas = json_decode($datas);
```

How can I write this code more simply?

Comment: We cannot fetch any data from your database, so we don't know what your data looks like. This makes, what you're doing with it, a bit of a mystery. Could you please add an data example to your question, in other words, what goes in and what goes out? It is also normal, here on Code Review, to tell what the code is used for: Why does this code exists?

Comment: @rizkaps Please edit your question to supply the requested/missing information?  This may lead to this page being reopened and potentially gaining upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

**Please don't ever perform surgery on a JSON string**.

I see that you are trying to flatten your multidimensional indexed array of indexed arrays into an indexed array.

This is far simpler, more stable, and more professionally done in your loop.

First, if you are not retaining the table column name as the key in your result array, then don't call `fetchAssoc()`; use a method that will return indexed subarrays.

If your result set only has one column, then use:

```
$data[] = current($row);
```

If only one column and you use a fetching method which indexes the row values, then:

```
$data[] = $row[0];
```

If your result set has multiple columns, then I'd use a push&splat technique: (replace `fetchIndexed()` with the appropriate method from your project or otherwise call `array_values()` before spreading `$row`)

```
$data = [];
while ($row = $this->db->fetchIndexed($res_weight)) {
    array_push($data, ...$row);
}
```

Either way, your result array will be a flat, indexed array and you can `json_encode()` it and move on.